# Allegro mouse button released

Tags: c++, mouseevent, allegro5

I want to make an Allegro 5 program , where the cursor must change it's appearance when the mouse button is pressed . As far as I understand this statement `events.type!=ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_UP` never becomes false . But I can't understand why because after releasing the button the loop doesn't stop . Can you tell me where my mistake is and if there is a better alternative way ?

```
        while(loop){
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
        ALLEGRO_EVENT events;
        al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &events);
        if(events.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE){
            loop=false;
        }
        if(events.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_AXES ){
            x=events.mouse.x;
            y=events.mouse.y;
            buffer = released;
        }
        if( events.type==ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN)
            while (events.type!=ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_UP){
                x=events.mouse.x;
                y=events.mouse.y;
                al_draw_bitmap(pressed, x , y , NULL );
                al_flip_display();
                al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb( 0 , 0 , 0));
            }

        al_draw_bitmap(released, x , y , NULL );
        al_flip_display();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never check for new event inside `while (events.type!=ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_UP)` loop and the value of events.type cannot ever change.

Your program is already running in a loop (`while(loop){`), there is no need to create another one. You should create a new variable that depends on the state of `ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_UP` and changes the position of your mouse, etc...

Something like that: ( pseudo code!)

```
    while(loop){
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
    ALLEGRO_EVENT events;

    _Bool change = false ;

    al_wait_for_event(event_queue, &events);
    if(events.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE){
        loop=false;
    }
    if(events.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_AXES ){
        x=events.mouse.x;
        y=events.mouse.y;
        buffer = released;
    }
    if( events.type==ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_DOWN)
        change = true ;
     if( events.type==ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_UP)
        change = false ;


    if( change )
        al_draw_bitmap(pressed, x , y , NULL );
    else
        al_draw_bitmap(released, x , y , NULL );

    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb( 0 , 0 , 0));
    al_flip_display();

}
```

Comment: I have tried this method , but the problem is that it only shows the pressed cursor picture for a second , and when I change the mouse position without releasing the button it shows the released picture again ...

Comment: @Sam379 My code is not the SOLUTION but an example how to more properly structure your events. In this case you should make the `change` variable `static`.